# Django - MyThing.objects.filter(name=None) vs MyThing.objects.filter(name__isnull=True) - which is better?

Tags: django, django-models, null, django-queryset

I have a table and want to find all rows where the `name` column is None.

Should I do:

```
MyThing.objects.filter(name=None)
```

or

```
MyThing.objects.filter(name__isnull=True)
```

What difference does it make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs for [`exact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exact) and [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull), these produce the same SQL. Which you use is more of a stylistic choice than a performance or correctness one.

Answer (score 2):

A quick check in the console outputted something like the following for me:

```
str(MyThing.objects.only('name').filter(name=None).query)
# 'SELECT `myapp_mything`.`id`, `myapp_mything`.`name` FROM `myapp_mything` WHERE `myapp_mything`.`name` IS NULL ORDER BY `myapp_mything`.`name` ASC'

str(MyThing.objects.only('name').filter(name__isnull=True).query)
# 'SELECT `myapp_mything`.`id`, `myapp_mything`.`name` FROM `myapp_mything` WHERE `myapp_mything`.`name` IS NULL ORDER BY `myapp_mything`.`name` ASC'
```

So they appear to be the same.